# I have a valve power supply with two outputs and want to switch a built in ammeter between the two without supply interruption

Tags: current

A valve power supply has two outputs, V1 is 700Vdc and V2 is 450Vdc.
I want to switch a 300mA ammeter between the two without interrupting either supply.
I attempted to use relays to switch the ammeter in and out of either circuit, but the switching action causes a supply interruption.
I now want to put a low value resistor, say 1ohm, in series with each supply and then use the 300mA meter as a voltmeter to measure the voltage across the resistor. This way I can switch the meter between the two supplies without interrupting either.
The voltmeter should have its own supply (say 12V which is available) for the 300mA meter.
The reason for wanting to use the 300mA meter (and complicating the issue) is because its what I have on hand (old style antique) and I have already cut the hole in the chassis for it. Oh dear.

Comment: His problem is obvious. Can't you two think of a solution?

Comment: it takes more relays, but it's straightforward to switch one ammeter between circuits without breaking current to the load. Arrange two of the relays to short the ammeter connection point, close these first, open last.

Comment: In order to convert a 300 mA analog current meter into a 300 mV volt meter, you must remove the internal shunt resistor (Unknown 1 or 2 ohm range) and put a similar range value in series to convert mA to mV , It might be 250 mV full scale @ 50 uA but I don't know, then shunted internally. Can you measure it's R value? then replace it to match 300 mA with voltage and 2 external shunts with a switch

Comment: Switch a voltmeter between two permanently connected shunts.

Comment: You need to think about safety. If the 'old style' meter has an exposed metal zero-adjust screw, it might be live and dangerous to touch. I knew of a radio ham who had a home built transmitter with a PA stage valve/tube with 1200v on the plate/anode, and a front panel mounted meter to measure the current, and the meter screw killed him. He only brushed it momentarily. 700v at the current range mentioned can definitely kill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyPUQn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

All 300 mA meters are simply 50 uA or 100 uA with internal shunts. I expect these are 100 uA full scale (FS) with internal shunts to any desired scale. But to convert to voltmeter with a 1 Ohm external shunt requires replacing the internal shunt after you take it apart and confirm the resistance or full scale current without the shunt.

Comment: Tony I opened the meter up and it is indeed a 50uA meter with a shunt.
So I will remove the shunt and use a 10 turn preset to calibrate it as a voltmeter.

Comment: Not a 10 turn R.. Rather measure and compute 1% R  can be quite different 10k?

Comment: If this also measures surge currents charging capacitors, you will want a diode 
 limiiter

Comment: The ! ohm res. with 300 mA exceeds 1/4 W so 1/2W is needed or more

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using relays to **break** the connection and insert the ammeter when you want to make a measurement, use the relay to **short across** the ammeter when you **do not** want to make a measurement.

The connection is never broken, and you can control when the shunt resistance of the ammeter becomes part of the circuit. If the current is too high during certain times, just short across the shunt resistance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to take some action to decide which of the two supplied you read. This solution requires that you take two actions, one to select which supply to read, then the other to read. The selection could be using a DPDT switch, or relay. The read action could use a single pole NC relay, or could use a NC push button.

This solution can read completely isolated supplies, though I would imagine that your supplies would probably share a common return. Note that the select switch or relay should be a break-before-make type (most are, it's only in rotary switches that you can get a make-before-break option) to avoid shorting the supplies to each other.

[image: schematic]

Obviously, if you push the 'read' button on the deselected supply, you'll kill the power. Perhaps that can be obviated with a diode shunted across the switch, 0.7 V drop is as nothing compared to 450 V! Just make sure the ammeter drop doesn't exceed (say) 400 mV and there will be negligible diode conduction. (For some strange reason, I don't appear to be able to edit the schematic to show this)

Comment: Neil I did consider your solution before my post, but by using the meter relay to switch the read relay to enable break before make, but I thought this might be too risky with the high voltages.